# Action Bar not going back to normal after search

Tags: android, android-intent, searchview

I am using `onNewIntent()` and `handleIntent()` to use my search query in the activity in which it is searched and not launch a new activity, but after I search, my activity title does not return. Instead there is an icon with a back button, and the search icon next to it, not all the way to the right where it should be. When I press the back button it goes back to how it should be.  I have tried using `onBackPressed()` to simulate this back press, but it closes the original activity as well. I am not sure why this is happening, is my searching activity staying up for some reason?

Here is the related code in my main activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(cn));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean queryTextFocused) {
            if(!queryTextFocused) {
                searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
                searchView.setQuery("", false);
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    // check if search intent
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        onNewIntent(intent);
    } else {
        super.startActivity(intent);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        search(query);//this is my own method, performs search opeations
        searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some screenshots ?

Comment: I dont think screenshots are really necessary, it isn't too hard to describe what it looks like, although perhaps I didn't do a good enough job.

Once I press search, in the actionbar is the little default application icon (green android) with a small back arrow to its left... same as anytime there is an activity to go back to. Directly to its right is the search icon (magnifying glass), and there is no activity title.

It should still have the app icon with arrow in left corner, but there should be the activity name to its right and the search icon all the way to the right.

Comment: Is there anything else I should have described?

Comment: so you want to close the searchView ?

Comment: the searchview is iconified, the problem is that it seems like another activity is being displayed, I guess the search activity, but that activity is not going through its onCreate() method so I dont know

Comment: Share some screenshots, please